# Unexpected token undefined in JSON at position 10

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```js
const propCSS = resposta['propCSS'];

const listData = getList(cssList);
listData.lista = propCSS;

for (let i = 1; i <= list.length; i--) {
  list.push(` "$ {listData}" `);
  console.log(lista);
}
```

I'm trying to add an item to an array in a JSON file, but the result only returns me `undefined` at position 10.

Comment: Many programming languages number things from 0. So if you have a 10-element list, the valid indices are 0, 1, 2, ... 9 (while `length` is 10). And thus an upwards counting loop would be `for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++)`, `i<list.length`, because `list.length` (10) is not a valid index. Counting downwards is a bit longer as `i` still can't be `list.length`, and `i` can be 0: `for(let i=list.length-1; i>=0; i--)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an error in your for loop implementation.
You are loopping trough an array starting from the position 1 (`let i = 1`) till the end of the array, but you are descreasing the iterator (`i--`).
So your loop goes like: list[1] then list[0] then list[-1]... and an array can't have negative indexes.
You need to increase you iterator (i++) or start your loop from the end of the array till the begining: `for (let i = list.length-1; i === 0; i--) { //push() }`

Also, is this all of your code? If it is, then `list.length` and `list.push()` won't work because there is no `list` declared. Same thing for the `console.log(lista)`, there's no `lista` declared.